# Intelli-j tomcat server console encoding issue with log4j's encoding=UTF-8?

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, encoding, utf-8

I have a strange problem that I use `log4j` to print logs to console that prints wrong character, but use `System.out.println` works fine.

I have explicitly set encoding to UTF-8:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,console,error
####################Conole logs######################
log4j.appender.console= org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.encoding=UTF-8  ###Here , if I commented this line, it works fine
log4j.appender.console.Threshold = DEBUG
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern = %-d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}  [ %t:%r ] - [ %p ]  %m%n
```

The same line, I use :

```
        LogUtil.debug(line);
        System.out.println("from system.out: "+line);
```

Console:

```
DEBUG - 閭ｄ簺骞存垜浠竴璧疯拷杩囩殑濂冲=鑷存垜浠粓灏嗛�濆幓鐨勯潚鏄�
from system.out: 那些年我们一起追过的女孩=致我们终将逝去的青春
```

But if I commented out the `log4j.appender.console.encoding=UTF-8`, it work!

Please note that the exsting code works fine when I used eclipse before, but today I tried to run it at my IDEA14 then find the problem.

Guess it may be some encoding setting issue on the default console?

PS: I set project's encoding to UTF-8 as well

Comment: That would be my guess as well.  When you explicitly specify log4j's encoding, it overrides the default behavior.  I believe the default behavior is to simply let the System.Out.Print() function take care of the encoding transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses environmental cues to set the appropriate encoding on `System.out`, such as `locale` or codepage (`chcp`).

AFAIK, Intellij uses the Character Encoding of the project to set the interpreted console encoding.

By defining the encoding in Log4j, there's a chance you'll double encode or choose the wrong encoding, as you've found.

Comment: I set the project encoding to utf-8, so do you mean that I am double encoding the message : `By defining the encoding in Log4j, there's a chance you'll double encode `

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify an encoding in log4j, the platform's default encoding will be used.

You can change encoding in Intellij to match that in log4j though (https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/configuring-output-encoding.html)

I don't use IntelliJ, so I haven't tried this.